# Como impedir que o Multi Touch permita toques em dois itens da ListView ao mesmo tempo

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de Vendas/Orçamentos, e estou com um problema em um ***listview*** personalizado, onde o usuário está conseguindo clicar em 2 linhas ao mesmo tempo, chamando 2 vezes os eventos e causando exceção no banco de dados.
eu preciso desativar este *multitouch*, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Aqui tem um *print* da aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Experimente usar a propriedade [`splitMotionEvents`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#splitMotionEvents) no layout da sua `ListView`:

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

Comment: Boa Tarde @Paulo Rodrigues, obrigado por sua sugestão. Já tentei utilizar esta propriedade, porem, não funcionou como eu preciso, pois com esta propriedade no listView, eu não consigo clicar os 2 ao mesmo tempo, porem se der 2 toques um logo apos o outro em um item do listView, o dialog que é chamado no evento estoura 2 vezes, ao qual na segunda vez gera exceção. Tem como será definir tipo um delay no listView de 500 milissegundos, até que o dialog abra?

Comment: @PauloVescovi, acho que nesse caso você teria que tratar usando alguma flag ou verificando se o Diálogo já esta sendo exibido. Que eu saiba não tem como limitar a taxa de tratamento de eventos.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão @Wakim, vou tentar aqui. vlw

Comment: @PauloVescovi A resposta certa a essa pergunta é essa. Essa solução só não resolve para você porque seu problema é outro. Sugiro que aceite essa resposta e abra uma pergunta específica sobre os clique simultâneos muito rápidos.